# Как из значения ID (автоинкремент) получить значения вида 0001, 0002, 0003?

Tags: sql, sql-server, инкремент

Имеется таблица, условно, такого вида:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Actavia] (
    [Id]          BIGINT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [DocIndex]          NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
);
```

SQL по умолчанию в столбец Id  при создании записей проставляет значения вида 1, 2, 3, 4 и т.д.
Как можно получить значения вида 0001, 0002, 0003, 0004 для формирования записи в столбце [DocIndex] ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @x int
select @x=1
select @x,format(@x,'0000')
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это использовать, если я заполняю [DocIndex] с помощью триггера, а именно  в [DocIndex] вносится следующее НО= CONCAT('R.', Id, '.Vi') ?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
   .....
   UPDATE Actavia
   SET [DocIndex]=RIGHT(CONCAT('000',cast (i.Id AS NVARCHAR(MAX))),4) --в этой строке берем данные которые вы вносите (i.Id, то есть из inserted)
   FROM Actavia X
   JOIN inserted i ON X.id = i.id
```

то есть в любом случае Вы можете использовать следующий код для получения значений вида 000N, где N- ваш Id:

```
 [DocIndex]=RIGHT(CONCAT('000',cast (Id AS NVARCHAR(MAX))),4)
```

Comment: На основании примера выше, просто сделал 
   [DocIndex]= CONCAT('R.', format(Id, '0000'), '.Vi')

Comment: Так у вас получилось? Просто смотрите, функция format обычно используется для форматирования вывода информации, т.е. представление в определенном требуемом виде, но для использования в Update я бы порекомендовала Вам все же код RIGHT(CONCAT('000',cast (UserId AS VARCHAR(MAX))),4), обычно такого типа код используют в операторах модицикации данных Обычно на работу функции format могут влиять языковые настройки, хотя в Вашем случае не должно, но все же